# Android UI Default Margin Remove

Tags: android, xml

[image]

I am trying to remove those auto Margins from my Layout,

Here is my Layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:weightSum="3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.shifz.bardofavon.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
android:weightSum="3"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="Quotes"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="Quotes"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >   
            <Button
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="MostWeight"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
android:weightSum="3"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Biography"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Biography"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think button will take some default margin and please try to replace Button with LinearLayout and check is not show extra space.

Comment: Use your `weight` property properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using weight property so for `Button` it will take some default margin. For avoid this there is two way.

1) Make your background of Button to Null. Like,

```
android:background="@null"
```

2) Apply Some background colour to your Button.

```
android:background="@color/red"
```

This two option will avoid your problem.