# Android | Java | How to remove default margins from relative layout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, default-value

I have a bottomsheet which includes a layout. And that layout has relative layout. Which has default margins. Even i set margins to 0dp it's not working.

**bottom_sheet_back.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_back"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

code inside
**activity_main.xml**

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_back"/>

        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

This is giving me result like this.

[image: result]

where as **bottom_sheet_back.xml** has full width.

[image: bottom_sheet_bacck]

As you can see in 1st image i want to remove that margins.

**Solution Tried**

1. [Android UI Default Margin Remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071142/android-ui-default-margin-remove)
2. [Android Remove default margins in RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326635/android-remove-default-margins-in-relativelayout)

Above solutions are not much help in my scenario. I tried one more solution and it was to edit `dimens.xml` but, I can't seem to find it anywhere. I use android studio 4.1.3 which has constraintLayout by default. So, `dimens.xml` is not generated by project. But, if it is not generated by project then how did `RelativeLayout` got margins?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get around your problem, i think theres aproblem with BottomAppbar, but if u change to BottomNavigationView it works very well with no problem, it removes the default margin

here is the code for the Bottom navigation i used

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_back"/>

</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

thanks